# I can't create workable Libgdx project on Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, libgdx

I can't create workable Libgdx project on Eclipse.
No red marked visible compilation errors.
Just "!" symbol on the project name.

```
Errors:
Invalid ZIP archive: libs/armeabi-v7a/libgdx.so [in ...]
Invalid ZIP archive: libs/armeabi-v7a/libandroidgl20.so [in ...]
...
Invalid ZIP archive: libs/armeabi-v7a/libandroidgl20.so [in ...]
Invalid ZIP archive: libs/armeabi/libgdx.so [in ...]
```

Or sometimes I got strange error box:

```
Launch configuration CacheLineSize references non-existing project game1.
```

BTW, Eclipse is so uncomfortable that I can't open and close project. All projects in a pile...
But my main problem that I can't create final apk for Libgdx project in IntelliJ IDEA.
(apk is small with no images, proguard errors).
And so I try to create release apk on eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you have problem in your libraries. go and download latest libs from this [Link](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/downloads/list). and replace them with your current libs. java libs and android libs. (your problem is in android libs)
look, my english is not good, but i think you have problem with your apk and your images. images can set with latest sdk, you just select an image, then eclipse change it to correct sizes and for apk look for mario's tutorials. and finally, go in [LibGDX](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) site or their [Forum](http://badlogicgames.com/forum/) and look for your answer. i hope my reply help you.

Comment: you wrote: "images can set with latest sdk..". Thanks, but I could understand your thought concerning images and their sizes. Are you talking about images in /assets. I mentioned that IntelliJ's apk is too small. I guess there no files from /assets. BTW, Eclipse adds additional library to libs (android-support-v4.jar). Intellij IDEA does not add it to /libs

Comment: The same performance after replacing lingdx libraries with new ones.You said:"you have problem with your apk". Which apk? In Eclipse I can't compile the project. In intelliJ I can't create good workable final apk.

Comment: I wonder that I see android 2.1 library in Eclipse's properties-Java build path. I create project for Android 1.5. Maybe I have to add this appropriate library? But I don't know how...

Comment: if i understand it correct Intellij is a IDE. i use helios and juno, and i can run my libGDX project in it. and i test my project with android 2.3.3 and 4.0 , it worked well. hope i understand your problem well.

Comment: `The same performance after replacing lingdx libraries with new ones.` so try [This](http://http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/), i mean `nightlies` version.

Comment: I think, that replacing libraries will not help. Libgdx libraries worked okay in Android IntelliJ IDEA projects . Maybe I should use another Eclipse? I use  Eclipse classic  3.7.2

Comment: the official eclipse that is for developers is helios. you can go to this [Address](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/junor) and download it.

Comment: Okay , I will try. But I saw somewhere recommendation to use Eclipse Classic. It seems I don't feel difference between Eclipse versions. Eclipse Classic is bigger that IDE for Java. Maybe so classic is more powerful?

Comment: idk... i don't work with classic. maybe you right. it's not very big different between Eclipse versions.